# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native

When i start remote js debugging from the dev menu and reload my react-native app in the android simulator this error appears:

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTView" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView
    in Root
    in Styled(Root)
    in _default
    in Provider
    in StyleProvider
    in App
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in AppContainer
getNativeComponentAttributes
    43f126e6-e124-4b3e-b0e6-b141bfd6e007:28263:5
<unknown>
    43f126e6-e124-4b3e-b0e6-b141bfd6e007:13523:14
Object.exports.get
    43f126e6-e124-4b3e-b0e6-b141bfd6e007:21438:20
completeUnitOfWork
    43f126e6-e124-4b3e-b0e6-b141bfd6e007:20492:64
performUnitOfWork
    43f126e6-e124-4b3e-b0e6-b141bfd6e007:20598:30
renderRoot
    43f126e6-e124-4b3e-b0e6-b141bfd6e007:20618:28
performWorkOnRoot
    43f126e6-e124-4b3e-b0e6-b141bfd6e007:21020:268
performWork
    43f126e6-e124-4b3e-b0e6-b141bfd6e007:20995:7
requestWork
    43f126e6-e124-4b3e-b0e6-b141bfd6e007:20940:95
```

Comment: Please add code

Comment: @ShashinBhayani which code should i add?

Answer (score 12):

I experienced this on Android when I tried to start remote JS debugging while JS Dev Mode was turned off. I fixed it by going to the Dev Settings menu and re-enabling dev mode.

Comment: Copied this to: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22725#issuecomment-511466881

Comment: where is that js dev mode ?? in android or chrome?