# How can I disable RCTView?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm trying to build android app with react native.

I kept getting this error:

```
ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTView" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:133)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:41)
    in Project(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:57), js engine: hermes
```

but this was solved by enabling debug mode in the app, as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532052/invariant-violation-requirenativecomponent-rctview-was-not-found-in-the-uima).

But now, I need to use [`react-native-reanimated2`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs), and unfortunately the package does not support debug mode (the app crashes immediately in debug mode).

It is written in the docs that:

...
As the library uses JSI for synchronous native methods access, remote debugging is no longer possible. You can use Flipper for debugging your JS code, however connecting debugger to JS context which runs on the UI thread is not currently supported.
...

So how can I disable RCTView? I'm not using it in my own app source.